# how many bits generate aes.create() method in C#

Tags: c#, security, encryption, aes

I'm actually trying to make a secure file transfer program
and I would like to encrypt the sent file with the c# `Aes.Create()` method
but I wanted a AES-256 encryption and I'm not sure that the method does a 256 bits key
so I searched on Microsoft docs and many sketchy websites but I did find nothing.

So, how many bits generate `Aes.Create()`?

There is my code:

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
internal class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string original = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\SomePath");

        // Create a new instance of the Aes
        // class.  This generates a new key and initialization
        // vector (IV).
        using (Aes myAes = Aes.Create())
        {

            // Encrypt the string to an array of bytes.
            byte[] encrypted = EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(original, myAes.Key, myAes.IV);

            // Decrypt the bytes to a string.
            string roundtrip = DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(encrypted, myAes.Key, myAes.IV);

            //Display the original data and the decrypted data.
            Console.WriteLine("Original:   {0}", original);
            Console.WriteLine("Encrypted:  {0}", System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(encrypted));
            Console.WriteLine("Round Trip: {0}", roundtrip);
        }
    }
    static byte[] EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(string plainText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
    {
        // Check arguments.
        if (plainText == null || plainText.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");
        if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
        if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("IV");
        byte[] encrypted;

        // Create an Aes object
        // with the specified key and IV.
        using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
        {
            aesAlg.Key = Key;
            aesAlg.IV = IV;

            // Create an encryptor to perform the stream transform.
            ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

            // Create the streams used for encryption.
            using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                    {
                        //Write all data to the stream.
                        swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                    }
                    encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }

        // Return the encrypted bytes from the memory stream.
        return encrypted;
    }

    static string DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(byte[] cipherText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
    {
        // Check arguments.
        if (cipherText == null || cipherText.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("cipherText");
        if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
        if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("IV");

        // Declare the string used to hold
        // the decrypted text.
        string? plaintext = null;

        // Create an Aes object
        // with the specified key and IV.
        using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
        {
            aesAlg.Key = Key;
            aesAlg.IV = IV;

            // Create a decryptor to perform the stream transform.
            ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

            // Create the streams used for decryption.
            using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText))
            {
                using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                    {

                        // Read the decrypted bytes from the decrypting stream
                        // and place them in a string.
                        plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return plaintext;
    }
}
}
```

Yes, it's a modified version of Microsoft docs on `Aes` class: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aes

Comment: The size of the ciphertext in bytes is: `len+bs-(len%bs)`, where `len` is the number of bytes of the plaintext and `bs` is the blocksize (16 bytes for AES). This is because `Aes.Create()` applies CBC as mode and PKCS#7 as padding by default.

Comment: Also, decoding the ciphertext with the default encoding corrupts the ciphertext and therefore doesn't provide a meaningful value for the size. Btw, the number of bytes should be used as a measure (not the number of characters).

Comment: Do you want to know the key size, or the output size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[AES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) is a block cipher. That means it encrypts a fixed-sized block of clear text bytes into a same-sized block of cipher text bytes (hence the term [*block cipher*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher)). AES uses 128-bit blocks, i.e. 16 bytes long. This is irrespective of key size.

To be able to encrypt data of an arbitrary length, block ciphers use different [*modes* of operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation). Depending on the mode, padding is applied, an initialization vector may be used, [salt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) prepended, and dependencies between blocks are employed.

Hence, as a result, the *total size* of encrypted data may be slightly bigger than the original size of the unencrypted data. The difference accounts for (at least) the length of the initialization vector and/or salt and any padding to the nearest multiple of the cipher's block size.